# Iframe content not visible in IE6 and IE7

Tags: css, iframe, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, position

I am facing a problem with iframes in IE6 and IE7. I am trying to load iframe (containing static HTML) from same domain, no 3rd party plugins. But iframe content is not visible in both browsers.

I have used z-index as well but it is also not working. When applied a border to iframe to see if it is there, I found that iframe is there  but content is not there.

Comment: for iframe m using: <div class="lMid mt10"><iframe src="carousel.html" style="width:431px; height:310px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> </div>..........         and content in iframe is as follows...................           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/carousel.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="rs_cont1"> iframe content</div></body>
</html>

Comment: Is it visible in other browsers (versions)? And when you strip it down (remove all the css classes/divs/etc) can you make a minimal case?

Comment: ok please delete all code in your page and check only iframe it is working?

Comment: @Erno - It is working fine in IE8, FF and chrome... i even removed all css and divs in iframe html... still it is not working

Comment: Can you put the minimal html that doesn't work in your question (nicely formatted) so we can have a look? Is it a public site so we can test?

Comment: Iframe is as follows:


<div class="lMid mt10"><iframe src="carousel.html" style="width:431px; height:310px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> </div>


HTML called in iframe is as follows:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>kbckb</div>
</body>
</html>

CSS:

#jdPhotoViewer iframe{ border:1px solid red; position:relative; z-index:1000;}

Comment: This is not a minimal html. It still contains things we do not know or need (div, class IMid mt 10) What happens when you remove the div?

Comment: Please don't flag for mods because you can't find an answer.  We're janitors, not professors.  Also, conditional css.  Give into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few extraneous semicolons in the code that you posted. For example:

```
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"; lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

There should not be a semicolon after the attribute value for `xmlns`.

Nor should there be one at the end of this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">;
```

Also, as @Erno said, explicitly close `IFRAME` tags. These changes combined may fix the problem.

If it still doesn't work, try getting a very basic page inside the `IFRAME` to work, and troubleshoot from there as you add more elements back into the page. As soon as it stops working, you've identified a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is a difference between browser versions when it comes to closing an iframe tag. Try both

```
<iframe ... />
```

and

```
<iframe ... > ... </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using complete url for the src like src="http://localhost/mypage.html"

Answer (score 0):

Extensions like Adblock treat iframes as suspect. Try running your iframe code in a browser with any blocking extensions disabled. Chrome will let you know that an extension is blocking content but Firefox will simply not display it.